# Infer imported module default type in generic function [typescript]

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I have a simple module as follow:

```
// my-module.ts

interface IProps {
  prop1:string;
  prop2:string;
}

const someData:IProps = {
   prop1:'val1',
   prop2:'val2'
} ;

export default {
  someData:someData,
  title:'someTitle'
};
```

Assuming that I don't have access to the `IProps` interface, I can access the `someData` type like this:

```
import * as myModule from '../my-module.ts';

type SomeDataType = typeof myModule.default.someData;
```

However, I would like to pass `myModule` to a generic function and use the `someData` keys as follow:

```
import * as myModule from '../my-module.ts';
import { getPropValue} from '../helper.ts';

var val = getPropValue(myModule, 'prop1');
```

And the generic function:

```
// helper.ts

export function getPropValue<T>(module:T, propKey: keyof ? ) { // T.default.someData !!!
  return module.default.someData[propKey];
};
```

How can I access `default.someData` type in generic function parameter to get the object keys?

Answer (score 0):

here how I manage to do it:

```
// helper.ts
type ModuleDefault = { default: { someData: {} } };
export function getPropValue<T extends ModuleDefault>(module:T, propKey: keyof T['default']['someData'] ) {
};
```